# facebook graph - retrieve multiple photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve all photos that can be posted in a single Facebook post.
For example, in this [post](https://www.facebook.com/AtifAslamOfficialFanPage/posts/10153437154822143), there are two photos.
Using the Graph API (https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/AtifAslamOfficialFanPage/posts?fields=id,type,created_time,link,message,source,object_id&limit=10&access_token=xxx) I get for this post:

```
{
     "id": "182973122142_10153437154822143",
     "type": "photo",
     "created_time": "2016-03-18T17:47:23+0000",
     "link": "https://www.facebook.com/AtifAslamOfficialFanPage/photos/a.281303247142.151444.182973122142/10153437154412143/?type=3",
     "object_id": "10153437154412143"
  }
```

but there is only one object_id, which is the first photo of the post.

Is it possible to retrieve all photos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request the `attachments` field, [`182973122142_10153437154822143?fields=attachments`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=182973122142_10153437154822143%3Ffields%3Dattachments&version=v2.6), and you will get the following data structure:

```
{
  "attachments": {
    "data": [
      {
        "subattachments": {
          "data": [
            {
              "media": {
                "image": {
                  "height": 266,
                  "src": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/10314482_10153437154412143_7582591571482186627_n.png?oh=a2b350ce8ac6ae546022295c7e73245a&oe=579E6E12",
                  "width": 720
                }
              },
              "target": {
                "id": "10153437154412143",
                "url": "https://www.facebook.com/AtifAslamOfficialFanPage/photos/a.281303247142.151444.182973122142/10153437154412143/?type=3"
              },
              "type": "photo",
              "url": "https://www.facebook.com/AtifAslamOfficialFanPage/photos/a.281303247142.151444.182973122142/10153437154412143/?type=3"
            },
            {
              "media": {
                "image": {
                  "height": 720,
                  "src": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/p720x720/10314505_10153437154507143_8615151666809542144_n.jpg?oh=4255fb5699cf0a4d5c455be82cbb8efe&oe=57E38281",
                  "width": 720
                }
              },
              "target": {
                "id": "10153437154507143",
                "url": "https://www.facebook.com/AtifAslamOfficialFanPage/photos/a.281303247142.151444.182973122142/10153437154507143/?type=3"
              },
              "type": "photo",
              "url": "https://www.facebook.com/AtifAslamOfficialFanPage/photos/a.281303247142.151444.182973122142/10153437154507143/?type=3"
            }
          ]
        },
        "target": {
          "id": "10153437154822143",
          "url": "https://www.facebook.com/AtifAslamOfficialFanPage/posts/10153437154822143"
        },
        "title": "Photos from Atif Aslam's post",
        "type": "album",
        "url": "https://www.facebook.com/AtifAslamOfficialFanPage/posts/10153437154822143"
      }
    ]
  },
  "id": "182973122142_10153437154822143"
}
```